# TCP checksum 3.0 version

Tags: c++, tcp, network-protocols, checksum, winpcap

i am here again to calculate the TCP checksum.

I need add pseudoheader tcp + tcp header + tcp payload.
All must be added in pieces of 16 bits as you should known.

In my code the first thing i do it is added to "sumando" (the variable which loads the checksum)  the pseudoheader.
After that i add the header tcp from unsigned short to unsigned short.
After that i add the payload tcp from unsigned short to unsigned short.

Finally i do the complement of my tcp checksum and i transform it to 2 bytes. And it should be work, but it dosent work.

I am using winpcap to catch the packets from my computer and recalculate the tcp checksum. Open wireshark you can see in which byte starts the fields.

```
//http://www.arcesio.net/checksum/checksumTCP.html
u_char* tcp_checksum(const u_char* _datos, int _tamaño)
{
u_char *checksum = new u_char[2];
u_short sumando = 0, sumanda = 0;
bitset<17> controlador;

if (_tamaño < 54)
    return nullptr;

//sumo ip origen e ip destino
for (int i = 26; i < 33; i++){
    sumanda = (u_short)((_datos[i] << 8) + _datos[i + 1]);
    controlador = sumando + sumanda;
    sumando += sumanda;
    if (controlador[16] == 1)
        sumando++;
    i++;
}

//sumo el byte de ceros y el numero de protocolo TCP
sumanda = (u_short)0x06;
controlador = sumando + sumanda;
sumando += sumanda;
if (controlador[16] == 1)
    sumando++;

//sumamos el tcp segment len
sumanda = (u_short)((_datos[16] << 8) + _datos[17]) - ((u_short)((_datos[46] & 0xF0) >> 4) + 
(u_short)(_datos[14] & 0x0F)) * 4;
//cout << "tcpseglen: " << sumanda;
cout << " tamaño: " << _tamaño << " ";
controlador = sumando + sumanda;
sumando += sumanda;
if (controlador[16] == 1)
    sumando++;

//YA TENEMOS SUMADO EL PSEUDO HEADER BIEEEEEN

//sumo todo el campo de cabecera con el checksum a cero
for (int i = 34; i < 53; i++){
    if (i != 50){
        sumanda = (u_short)((_datos[i] << 8) + _datos[i + 1]);
        controlador = sumando + sumanda;
        sumando += sumanda;
        if (controlador[16] == 1)
            sumando++;
    }
    i++;
}
//suponiendo un tamaño de 20 bytes de cabecera siempre..

//sumo todo el payload tcp
for (int i = 54; i < _tamaño; i++){
    if (i + 1 == _tamaño && _tamaño % 2 == 0){//se desborda entonces copiamos solo el ultimo, pero estará ya copiado??
        sumanda = (u_short)_datos[_tamaño - 1];
        controlador = sumando + sumanda;
        sumando += sumanda;
        if (controlador[16] == 1)
            sumando++;
        break;
    }
    sumanda = (u_short)((_datos[i] << 8) + _datos[i + 1]);
    controlador = sumando + sumanda;
    sumando += sumanda;
    if (controlador[16] == 1)
        sumando++;
    i++;
}

u_short original;
original = (_datos[50] << 8) + _datos[51];
sumando += 20;
sumando = sumando & 0xFFFF;
sumando = ~sumando;
//cout << "checksum original: " << original << endl;
//cout << "checksum calculado: " << sumando << endl;
checksum[0] = (sumando >> 8) & 0x00FF;
checksum[1] = sumando & 0x00FF;
return checksum;
}
```

I pass a tcp packet to this function (packet catched with winpcap).
I compare my tcp checksum with the real tcp checksum of the packet, and this is and example of output, original tcp cheksum and mine tcp checksum respectively:

```
6e9==6e9
75a==75a
fe1e==fe1e
8c3e==8c3e
73ed==73ed
8a52==8a52
844d==841d
dad2==dac4
5cde==5cde
e2d1==e2d1
```

When the packet is not odd i just need to add 20 to my cheksum to get the original i dont know why but it works.. but i dont want to do it evidently, if the packet is odd the difference between checksums is not a constant.

What is wrong with my code? Please help.

Regardes Kaxper!

Comment: This isn't clear - these checksums match, so what is the problem?

Comment: No, it does not. It only matches when it is pair and when i add 20 to my final checksum, otherwise it always fails.

Comment: You don't need to write this code. There is an RFC that provides it. Just look it up.